# WPF Custom control template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have made one custom user control (search text box), which basically consists of one dock panel, and in the panel there are two controls: textbox and button.

I have set some default appearance for this control, which consists of setting a border on the user control, and setting no borders and no background on the textbox, and I have created a custom style for the button. So far this control looks the way I want, and is working correctly.

The problem arises when I want to allow themes for my application. When I put custom styles for basic windows controls (Button, TextBox, ListBox, etc), they are displayed properly with the new theme. But I don't know how to make a template for my custom control. Any attempt ended up in the control not showing at all at runtime.

What exactly must be done in the new template for this control? Do I need to make a template for the User control, and for the textbox and the button controls also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up user controls and custom controls here. What you described above is a user control, and you cannot apply new templates to it.

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for the response.

Now when I know the difference between the two, I have made a custom control, and again eveyrthing is ok, except for the styling. Now I am able to style, but I need answers to these questions:

- Do I need to restyle all the controls in my custom control?
- If yes, then if I need to create both style and template, then basically I am redesigning the control again - where is the benefit (except that I don't need to do c$ code)?
- I have an image resource for my control. Do I need to provide this image again when restyling?